# Purview API - Extracting all server guids from collections?

Tags: azure-purview

I'm currently building a pipeline using the purview atlas API to extract server guids, and from there, extract database guids, and so on and so forth until the column level. But don't see any API endpoints that allows me to extract all possible server guids from a collection? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not possible at this moment.

Could you please check this document to get list of guids:- [Discovery - Query - REST API (Azure Purview) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/discovery/query#discovery_query)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could solve your problem, but here is what I do:

In my case, I need to extract the dictionary from Purview. To do that, i do the following:

```
pv glossary read
```

from that, i get a json with all the guid. Then,

```
pv glossary readDetailed --glossaryGuid= <<guids have found>>
```

I will just leve it here as  a response just in case you can get anythig from this.

Thank you